# span, strong, em inside a in ckeditor of TYPO3 9/10

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

is there a possibility to configure ckeditor that he allows tags like span, strong or em inside a link? When i select text which contains bold or some other styles with span and classes and put a link on this selection, all tags within the selection will be stripped. This happens just when the link wizard is closed.

When i add the link in source it works, the tags end up inside the a tag as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm behavior. But if I set the link first and then make some text inside in bold it works as expected without HTML editing.

Comment: Thanks Heinz, good idea, i never tried it this way round :-) It seems that it is not a problem of ckeditor but of the link wizard in TYPO3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heinz Schilling gave me the hint to change the order: first make the link and then add the other tags or styles to a selection within the link. This worked and gave me the expected results in back- and frontend.

As i expected earlier, this seems not to be a problem of ckeditor but of the link wizard of TYPO3. The link wizard eliminates all tags within the selected link text.